# Como capturar valor de um parágrafo dentro de uma div?

Tags: html, div

Peço o auxilio de vocês para conseguir capturar o valor de um parágrafo `h4` que está dentro de uma `div` específica, e colocar em um campo texto de um formulário.  É para automatizar um sistema de resposta do nome do grupo/cantor de uma rádio on line.

Esta é a `div` onde está a informação que preciso:

```
<div class="player">
    <div>
      <h4>CANTOR</h4>
      <h5>MÚSICA</h5>
      <span></span>
    </div>"
```

Answer (score 2):

A primeira coisa que você deve fazer é capturar esse elementos. Você pode fazer isso através de um `id`, da seguinte maneira:

#### HTML

```
<h4 id="cantor">CANTOR</h4>
<h5 id="musica">MÚSICA</h5>
```

#### Javascript

Para selecionar o elemento pelo id usa-se o `document.getElementById()`. Ou o `document.querySelector("#ID")`, utilizando, no último caso, o seletor `#`.

```
var cantor = document.getElementById("cantor").innerHTML;
var musica = document.getElementById("musica").innerHTML;
```

Já a captura do que está dentro se faz com o método `.innerHTML`. Todo o código acima está em Javascript Puro.

### Exemplo

Como você não disponibilizou o código de sua caixa de texto, criei uma:

```js
var cantor = document.getElementById("cantor").innerHTML;
var musica = document.getElementById("musica").innerHTML;

var input = document.getElementById("textoCopia");

input.value = cantor + " - " + musica;
```

```html
<div class="player">
  <div>
    <h4 id="cantor">CANTOR</h4>
    <h5 id="musica">MÚSICA</h5>
    <span></span>
  </div>
</div>

<input type="text" id="textoCopia">
```

### Edição

Como este código já vem pronto e você já possui uma `class="player"`, basta selecioná-la e a partir dela ter acesso ao elemento `h4` e `h5`. Você pode fazer isso assim, já que está usando JQuery:

```js
var cantor = $('.player div h5').text();
var musica = $('.player div h4').text();

$('input').val(cantor + " - " + musica);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="player">
  <div>
    <h4>CANTOR</h4>
    <h5>MÚSICA</h5>
    <span></span>
  </div>
</div>

<input type="text">
```

Veja se lhe serve, não acrescentei nada ao HTML, apenas fiz a seleção com JQuery e acrescentei uma `input` como exemplo.

Comment: Boa Noite Samir,

Esqueci de informar, o conteúdo H4 e H5 vem de uma página da Rádio on Line.  Mesmo assim eu consigo inserir aquele id dentro do resultado que já vem pronto?

É exatamente isso que eu estou precisando, na verdade só colocar o nome do Cantor/Grupo no Formulário.

Obrigado por equanto.

Grato,
Jairo Almeida

Comment: Tudo bem, há várias outras maneiras, mas como essas páginas são inseridas? Iframe, include? E mais uma coisa, você está usando Jquery?

Comment: Oi Samir,

Na Home da Rádio aparece o nome do cantor/grupo e o nome da musica. Consegui a URL direta que mostra as mesmas informações sem formatação:

<div class="player">
  <script type="text/javascript">
    setTimeout(function() { $.get("/musics/playing", function(data) { $('#player').html(data); }) }, 10000);
  </script>
</div>

Comment: Oi Samir,

Na Home da Rádio aparece o nome do cantor/grupo e o nome da musica. Consegui a URL direta:

radio.com/musics/playing.php

Quando está tocando alguma musica aprece aquela DIV Player com aqueles H4 e H5 e a cada musica que toca ele muda os valores.

Quando não está tocando nenhuma música a Div fica somente com o script que pega as músicas quando ela está tocando que é esta:

<div class="player">
  <script type="text/javascript">
    setTimeout(function() { $.get("/musics/playing", function(data) { $('#player').html(data); }) }, 10000);
  </script>
</div>

Comment: @jairoalmeida Acho que seria o caso de fazer outra pergunta com estes novos detalhes, porque a pergunta original está respondida imho, e bem respondida. Claro que alguém ainda pode fazer outra resposta complementando esta, com outra variação do mesmo resultado por exemplo, mas acho que além de talvez Samir, o Santo rsrs, ninguém mais vai adentrar nestes detalhes que vc postou nos comentários, simplesmente porque eles não estão na pergunta.